# Forcing new scopes on MSAL iOS to acquireTokenInteractively

Tags: ios, swift, azure-ad-msal

I have added a new scope to the array hoping that it will prompt the user to consent them. I'm using MSAL iOS 1.0.5 in Swift.

`let scopes = ["Files.ReadWrite", "Mail.Read"]`

But when it goes through the logic again, it never shows an interactive login to consent to the new scopes.

Should it not do this automatically if it detects a new scope the user has not consented before? Is there something I need to do to force this?

I'm using the code from the homepage of the github library at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc:

````
let scopes = ["your-scope1-here", "your-scope2-here"]

if let application = try? MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: config) {

    #if os(iOS)
    let viewController = ... // Pass a reference to the view controller that should be used when getting a token interactively
    let webviewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters(parentViewController: viewController)
    #else
    let webviewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters()
    #endif

    let interactiveParameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: scopes, webviewParameters: webviewParameters)
    application.acquireToken(with: interactiveParameters, completionBlock: { (result, error) in

    guard let authResult = result, error == nil else {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    // Get access token from result
    let accessToken = authResult.accessToken

    // You'll want to get the account identifier to retrieve and reuse the account for later acquireToken calls
    let accountIdentifier = authResult.account.identifier
    })
}
else {
    print("Unable to create application.")
}```
````